# How to prove that the matrix $A^k$ approaches $0$ as $k$ approaches infinity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

First of all, what does it mean to say an eigenvalue is "less than unity"?
I'm not exactly sure what this means.

Secondly, how do I show that  $\lim_{k\to\infty} A^k=0$ given that all eigenvalues of $A$ is less than unity?

Comment: An eigenvalue is "less than unity" if its module is less than one (here the inequality is strict). And here you could try to prove that $\|A\| < 1$ (for a well chosen norm)

Comment: Any matrix is similar to some triangular matrix. Triangular matrices have the property that the diagonal elements multiply only on themselves. It can be shown that the eigenvalues are on the diagonal. Modulus multiplies with multiplication and any number smaller than 1 raised to infty goes to 0.

Answer (score 4):

It means that $$\forall j \quad |\lambda_j(A)|<1$$ where $\lambda_j(A)$ are eigenvalues of $A$.

There're several different ways of showing that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}A^k=0.$$

The first method is based on the Jordan normal form of the matrix (this form helps to find another  expression for $A^k$). Essentially we show that any matrix is similar to an upper-triangular matrix $J$; the coefficients on the diagonal of $J$ are eigenvalues of $A$. After that it is easy to see that the powers of $J$ converge to zero and hence so do the powers of $A$.

The second method is based on the notion of spectral radius $\rho(A)$: on the one hand, for matrices it is equal to the biggest absolute value of eigenvalues of $A$ - in our case it means that $\rho(A)<1$; on the other hand, $\rho(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \|A^n\|^{1/n}$ if $\|\cdot\|$ is the spectral norm of $A$.

We can deduce from that the convergence $\|A^k\|\to 0$ and, by the definition of the norm, the convergence $A^k\to 0$.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on how to use the Jordan normal form to show this? Thanks